# bash: composer: command not found

Tags: php, bash, composer-php

On a server I want to do composer update/install and both give the error:

```
-bash: composer: command not found
```

I can see composer.phar, composer.json and composer.lock are there. How can I find out why I can't update?

Unfortunately the site is down at the moment because I get an error because one package isn't there at the moment.

**UPDATE:**

If I enter the following command:

```
php composer.phar install/update
```

everything seems to be working. Is there something I can do to change this or is it always necessary to enter the command this way?

Comment: `composer` is the command to use when it is installed globally on your machine. There is no disadvantage at all when using the Phar binary instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are on Linux / Unix / macOS**
You can do

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Note**: If the above fails due to permissions, you may need to run it again with sudo.

Now run composer in order to run Composer instead of php composer.phar.

**On Windows**

you need to set the directory to your PATH environment variable if it isn't already

Comment: i am getting the same error  mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

Composer is probably not installed on your machine.

Run this in your terminal to get the latest Composer version ([Source](https://getcomposer.org/download/)):

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55d6ead61b29c7bdee5cccfb50076874187bd9f21f65d8991d46ec5cc90518f447387fb9f76ebae1fbbacf329e583e30') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Alternative way: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos

Comment: tried the first command and the same message shows -bash: php: command not found

Comment: @user9437856 Do you have php installed? The message is different by the way.

Comment: Yes, PHP is installed.

Answer (score 3):

Moved it to the suggested location:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Still got “composer: command not found” when verifying the install?

Simply create a link to the /usr/bin location and voila!

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename file located in `/usr/local/bin` from `composer.phar` to `composer`

Comment: It helped on windows with git bash

Answer (score 1):

1. I set up an openserver
2. I have installed Composer (Composer-Setup.exe) 
   On windows 10, I added the composer to the PATH environment variable. as in the photo.

[image]

I also found the composer.bat file and ran it. 
(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat) 
These steps helped me.

Comment: This is good for Windows users

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ubuntu and have already moved the file with the mv function but still get this error or you get an error like ***"Command 'composer' is available in '/usr/local/bin/composer'"***

Try this to apply an alias as shown in the image below

Here is the command

```
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'
```

[screenshot of alias command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmPB2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can download Composer, globally or locally, here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
There is a clear and concise installation guide.
Once you've installed Composer, you'll be able to run the composer commands from any directory in your terminal.